# d3: setting classes for nodes doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, force-layout

first of all: please dont mark this question as already answered, I know there are lots of questions with setting classes in d3 but I did it the same way but nothing worked.

So this is my code:

```
const node = svg.append("g")
  .attr("stroke", "#fff")
  .attr("stroke-width", 3)
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)

  .attr("class", function (d) {

    console.log("I'm in creating classes for nodes")

    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < nodes.length; j++) {

        if (links[i].relation_type === "SHAREHOLDER") {

          console.log("found shareholder in links")

          if (links[i].source === nodes[j].id || links[i].target === nodes[j].id) {

            console.log("found shareholder in nodes" + i)

            return "shareholder"
          }
         }
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

and I dont even get console loged any of that code i write inside the class function. So for me it seems like he's not going into the `function(d) { for ....}`

Comment: Are you missing some code? You need to append the circles before you try and give them a class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're adding data to your circles, but we need to select and create some "new" circles as they don't exist yet. Adding the following lines after your existing "data" call should help.

```
.data(nodes)
.enter()
.append('circle')
```

You can find more about the enter/update pattern in d3 here: https://www.d3indepth.com/enterexit/